# Python dictionary creation?

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, jupyter-notebook, data-science

Hey so currently I've been trying to convert the text containing column of a csv file into a dictionary. From here I would then like to create word embeddings (& potentially embeddings for subparts of words. ie. dictionary => dict - tion - nary) What would be the best way to go about this, what frameworks would work best? I have attached my current code and an example of one row of the database.

```
# First we must input the data, we can use pandas to do this.
import pandas as pd
# Our data does not have headers so we will fabricate ones ourself during the importing
data = pd.read_csv('agr_en_train.csv', header=None, names =['Unique_ID', 'Text', 'Aggression-level'])
# We can now check the data has loaded properly.
data

{0}{facebook_corpus_msr_1723796}    {Well said sonu..you have courage to stand agai...} {OAG}
```

Please let me know if you require any other info the answer this question more adeptly. Additionally are there any recommended pre-created dictionaries. How would I utilise them, an answer or direction to any sources that would be helpful are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify the data format please?  Do the curly braces indicate columns in the dataframe?  And also for the desired output format.  You mention converting the column `Text` to a dictionary, what would you like as the keys and values of the dictionary?  I'm wondering whether the `pandas.DataFrame` method `to_dict` might be helpful but I'm not exactly sure what we're aiming for here.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you. I was able to work with my data using: data.df[Unique_ID]. I was incorrectly trying to create a string but was able to use a data frame to work with the data